# Total chromatic number bound implied by list coloring conjecture

Tags: graph-theory

**Total chromatic number** $(\chi '')$ is defined as the total number of colours needed to colour edges and vertices of a graph simultaneously with no adjacent vertices having the same colour and with no two incident edges having the same colour.

**List colouring conjecture** says that, the chromatic number of a line graph is equal to the choice number of the line graph.

I want to show that, if the list colouring conjecture is right, it implies that:

$$ \chi''(G) \leq \Delta(G) + 3$$

For a graph $G$ where $\Delta(G)$ is the maximum degree of any vertex in the graph $G$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is literally a one-line proof.

Comment: I believe the total chromatic number is usually defined with the further condition that, if a vertex $v$ is incident with an edge $e,$ then $v$ and $e$ must have different colours. With your definition, the vertex colouring and the edge colouring are independent of each other, and your "total chromatic number" is simply the maximum of the (vertex) chromatic number and the edge chromatic number.

Comment: For ***your*** definition of the total chromatic number, $\chi''(G)\le\Delta(G)+1$ by Vizing's theorem. For the real definition: first colour the vertices.

Comment: @MishaLavrov some of us are newbies. What seems trivial may be complex for someone. I just came across this question which happens to be of interest to me. I will appreciate any help :) I am learning for a prelim exam.

Comment: @holala Okay, I was young and foolish four years ago, and would not phrase the comment like that today. But start with bof's hint and you should do fine.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov. I'm solicitating your [advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4476155/dimension-of-a-standard-polyhedron); I got stuck with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4476155/dimension-of-a-standard-polyhedron)